# Use Carbon PHP to format a date

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I received this date of my database: 2017-02-06T22:25:12Z

I tried formatting it with Carbon php:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '2017-02-06T22:25:12Z')->toDateTimeString() }}
```

But this not works, I want this date format: 06-02-17 22:25:12

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `parse` method to get a quick and dirty conversion

```
Carbon::parse('2017-02-06T22:25:12Z')->format('d-m-y H:i:s');
```

If you are using a model to return this date you could also look at making it return as a `Carbon` object by adding it to the `protected $dates[]` array

Comment: Might wanna change that format function, it doesnt give the result you want

Answer (score 1):

If you add dates to your migration, be sure to mutate them on your model.

So on your model add the following:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'your_date'
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

If you mutate your date, it becomes a Carbon instance, which means you can use all carbon formatting tools.

From the docs:

> By default, timestamps are formatted as 'Y-m-d H:i:s'. If you need to
>   customize the timestamp format, set the $dateFormat property on your
>   model. This property determines how date attributes are stored in the
>   database, as well as their format when the model is serialized to an
>   array or JSON.

So if you would like to change the formatting everywhere use $dateFormat on your model like so:

```
 protected $dateFormat = 'd-m-y H:i:s';
```

If you only want to format your date inside your view , you can do it like so:

```
{{ $your_date->format('d-m-y H:i:s') }}
```

For more advanced formatting you can take a look at the carbon docs:
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/